# why has my username changed?

Tags: support

I was roux. I am now user456. what happened? (yes I have flushed my cache etc).

Comment: Yea that's totally bizarre. I thought you might have done it, but it showed you hadn't been online in 6 hours. I was participating in one of the questions you had answered and you showed up as roux about 40 mins ago. Next thing I know I saw you were user456.

Comment: I think the team checks meta for bug reports so they should see this and be able to answer it definitively, possibly. :) We've left it unchanged (blank) on the parent site.

Comment: Ahhhhh! It changed again. Now it's daniel. That's confusing...

Comment: Pretty sure he changed it himself, @yossarian; he even put a reference to the old name in his profile.

Comment: @aaron, hehe, I know. I was just taking the piss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems your display name became blank somehow.

I changed it back to roux just now

not sure how that might have happened... didn't even realise it was something mods could change

Comment: that only worked on meta...

Comment: @roux: You can edit your profile by going to your user page and clicking the "edit" link by your picture. We left it as-is on the parent site.

Answer (score 6):

This was actually a site-wide problem affecting the entire SE network.

It happened because they changed the authentication mechanism so that it's easier for people to sign in on multiple SE sites (some members here, myself included, participate on several).  Not all OpenID providers were affected, but myopenid (the one you're using) was one of them.

The issue didn't seem to affect people who changed their user name after registering, but for those people who use any of the affected OpenID providers and whose names were directly derived from their OpenID (never changed) - their display names disappeared.

It is possible that they'll fix this, but seeing as how it was a one-time incident, I doubt it; it'll be easier for you to edit your profile and manually change your name, as hobodave suggests.

Answer (score 3):

We no longer infer username from OpenID urls.

(this was never really correct anyway, and it meant nobody could respond to you in comments)

If you had a username that was inferred from your OpenID, you will now have to enter a real username.